# Задать в value значение для Firefox и Chrome в формате дд.мм.гггг

Tags: html5, google-chrome, дата

Задаю значение value в input type='date', но в Chrome отображаться не хочет.

```
<input type='date' pattern='(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]).(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:(?:30).(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|(?:31.(?:0[13578]|1[02]))).(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}' value='09.05.2017'/>
```

Если поставить value='2017-05-09' - тогда в Chrome показывает, но в Firefox так и идет в неправильном формате записи - '2017-05-09'.

**Javascript не будет использован в данном случае!**

Как заставить оба Firefox и Chrome показывать значение '09.05.2017'? Как-то можно для Chrome явно задать формат даты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не все браузеры [поддерживают](//caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) инпуты с датами. Соответственно, все браузеры, которые их не поддерживают, сделают инпут текстовым и отобразят в точности то значение, которое прописано в `value`.

Кстати, похоже, инпуты с датой в FF скоро появятся, т. к. уже есть под флагом.

Возможное решение - использовать два поля ввода, но показывать только одно из них в зависимости от поддержки инпутов с датами.

Это можно сделать не используя javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/s7bLsLu4/

```css
input[type="date"] {
  display: none;
}

#date-check:invalid ~ main input[type="date"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

#date-check:invalid ~ main input[type="date"] + input[type="text"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date-check" required value="not a date">
<main>
  <p>
    <input type="date" value="2017-05-09" />
    <input type="text" value="09.05.2017" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="date" value="2017-05-09" />
    <input type="text" value="09.05.2017" />
  </p>
</main>
```

Проверено в Chrome 58 (дата), FF 53 (текст), Edge 15 (дата) и IE 11 (текст).

Правда, с лейблами придётся тоже что-то намудрить.

Comment: Спасибо. Я надеялся, что как-то можно бы было через pattern для chrome указать формат записи, но по стандартам он отображает формат с настроек локали браузера. Пробовал два value cтавить, но непроглючило как надо все равно.

Comment: @CodeGust, обновил ответ. А уж как отображать, думаю пользователю виднее, если дата нативно поддерживается.

Comment: СпасиБо!!! Вот это здорово! Действительно отличное решение!